# Package ca-certificates is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I try to run this command `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates` on Ubuntu 22.04, but i get this output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package ca-certificates is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ca-certificates' has no installation candidate
```

Someone knows why I'm getting this error or What should I do?

I tried executing apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

It's important to note that I'm a novice in this field and I'm learning about it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` The package exists in the normal 22.04 repos (version 20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1), so it's reasonable to conclude that your sources are messed up.